# Getting mysql "connection refused" when trying to connect using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Here's the output from my mariadb log:

> $ sudo tail -f /opt/local/var/db/mariadb/rs012esb.mckenna.edu.err
>   130626  9:10:56 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure 130626 
>   9:10:56 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/rwlock_instances.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:10:56 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances'
>   has the wrong structure 130626  9:10:56 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find
>   file: './performance_schema/cond_instances.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:10:56 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has
>   the wrong structure 130626  9:10:56 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/file_instances.frm' (errno: 13) 130626  9:10:56
>   [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the
>   wrong structure 130626  9:10:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0
>   events 130626  9:10:56 [Note] /opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqld: ready
>   for connections. Version: '5.5.31-MariaDB'  socket:
>   '/opt/local/var/run/mariadb/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  Source distribution
>   130626  9:14:04 [Note] /opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqld: Normal
>   shutdown
>
> 130626  9:14:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>   130626  9:14:04  InnoDB: Starting shutdown... 130626  9:14:04  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence number 10740580 130626  9:14:04
>   [Note] /opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> 130626 09:14:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /opt/local/var/db/mariadb/rs012esb.mckenna.edu.pid ended 130626
>   09:14:25 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /opt/local/var/db/mariadb 130626  9:14:25 [Warning] Setting
>   lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for
>   /opt/local/var/db/mariadb/ is case insensitive 130626  9:14:25 InnoDB:
>   The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 130626  9:14:25 InnoDB: Mutexes and
>   rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 130626  9:14:25 InnoDB: Compressed
>   tables use zlib 1.2.8 130626  9:14:25 InnoDB: Initializing buffer
>   pool, size = 128.0M 130626  9:14:25 InnoDB: Completed initialization
>   of buffer pool 130626  9:14:25 InnoDB: highest supported file format
>   is Barracuda. 130626  9:14:25  InnoDB: Waiting for the background
>   threads to start 130626  9:14:26 Percona XtraDB
>   (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.31-MariaDB-30.2 started; log sequence
>   number 10740580 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/events_waits_current.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
>   130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/events_waits_history.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
>   130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/events_waits_history_long.frm' (errno: 13)
>   130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong
>   structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/setup_consumers.frm' (errno: 13) 130626  9:14:26
>   [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the
>   wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/setup_instruments.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments'
>   has the wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find
>   file: './performance_schema/setup_timers.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has
>   the wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/performance_timers.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers'
>   has the wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find
>   file: './performance_schema/threads.frm' (errno: 13) 130626  9:14:26
>   [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong
>   structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name.frm'
>   (errno: 13) 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name'
>   has the wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find
>   file: './performance_schema/events_waits_summary_by_instance.frm'
>   (errno: 13) 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong
>   structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name.frm'
>   (errno: 13) 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has
>   the wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/file_summary_by_event_name.frm' (errno: 13)
>   130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong
>   structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/file_summary_by_instance.frm' (errno: 13) 130626
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table
>   'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong
>   structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/mutex_instances.frm' (errno: 13) 130626  9:14:26
>   [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the
>   wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/rwlock_instances.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances'
>   has the wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find
>   file: './performance_schema/cond_instances.frm' (errno: 13) 130626 
>   9:14:26 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has
>   the wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file:
>   './performance_schema/file_instances.frm' (errno: 13) 130626  9:14:26
>   [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the
>   wrong structure 130626  9:14:26 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0
>   events 130626  9:14:26 [Note] /opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqld: ready
>   for connections. Version: '5.5.31-MariaDB'  socket:
>   '/opt/local/var/run/mariadb/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  Source distribution

mysql via PHP reports: Connection refused with mysql_error() call.
This has been working for months. Then, this morning, firing up my localhost mysql, nothing works.

Edit: Permissions seem quite fine:

```
# ls -l /opt/local/var/db/mariadb/performance_schema
total 416
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8624 Feb  7 14:01 cond_instances.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql    61 Feb  7 14:01 db.opt
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  9220 Feb  7 14:01 events_waits_current.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  9220 Feb  7 14:01 events_waits_history.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  9220 Feb  7 14:01 events_waits_history_long.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8878 Feb  7 14:01 events_waits_summary_by_instance.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8854 Feb  7 14:01 events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8814 Feb  7 14:01 events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8654 Feb  7 14:01 file_instances.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8800 Feb  7 14:01 file_summary_by_event_name.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8840 Feb  7 14:01 file_summary_by_instance.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8684 Feb  7 14:01 mutex_instances.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8776 Feb  7 14:01 performance_timers.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8758 Feb  7 14:01 rwlock_instances.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8605 Feb  7 14:01 setup_consumers.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8637 Feb  7 14:01 setup_instruments.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8650 Feb  7 14:01 setup_timers.frm
-rw-rw----  1 root  _mysql  8650 Feb  7 14:01 threads.frm
```

Ideas?

Comment: Which user account do you use to run `mysqld`?

Comment: cd '/opt/local' ; sudo /opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir='/opt/local/var/db/mariadb' 2>&1 &

Comment: I wouldn't run the database as root, but it should work. Also I'm surprised that the fix doesn't have anything to do with the errors in the log file.

Comment: Well, thanks again. Also, I have accepted your answer since you helped out so much to resolve this. I ended up finding the answer on the mysql doc relaying that this configuration disables listeners. I'm quite surprised myself! However, all the errors are now gone from the log upon restarting the daemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file: './performance_schema/rwlock_instances.frm' (errno: 13)

Check the file owners and access permissions. Error 13 is usually "permission denied."

Comment: pardon my ignorance but for which files?

Comment: The ones in the error messages: the directory `performance_schema` and everything under it. These are located in the MySQL/MariaDB data directory. Their owner should be the user you use for running the database.

Comment: I have many database owners but I'll check what the perms are

Comment: All of the files should be owned by the same user. If they are owned by different users the database engine can't read them.

Comment: Also, $ telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
However, I have 0 firewalls enabled

Comment: The database engine is not running, so naturally the OS refuses the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance so far!! It really has been helpful, honestly. I was able to *fix* it by commenting out skip-networking in the my.cnf file. This seems very crude and I don't understand why it's all of the sudden an issue